# Adding non-integer member values to IntEnum in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have roughly the following:

```
class Foo(IntEnum):
  a = 0
  b = auto()
  c = auto()
  strings = ["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie"]
  def __str__(self):
    return Foo.strings[self]
```

However, this raises:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'EnumMeta'
```

I need to have additional data inside my `Foo` class, but it appears that Python doesn't like that.

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly, or is there a better way to do this? I'm used to Enum Classes in C++.

Comment: You are trying to do something along the lines of `strings[Foo Object]` while python is expecting `strings[index as int, 0, 1 or 2]`

Comment: @BijayRegmi line 1 is what's throwing the error though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair bit of digging, I found a way to get the proper behavior that I was looking for. Firstly, I had to use `Enum` instead of `IntEnum`. Secondly, I had to upgrade to `Python3.11` and use the `nonmember` function to mark things that are not enumerable.

Comment: 3.11 is still in beta.  :-)  I'm glad the additions are working for you.  And yes, the problem was because it was trying to turn your list of strings into an integer.  Using `nonmember` should allow you to use `IntEnum`, though.